# Question regarding dynamic modeling of cable driven robot

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, complex-systems

I am studying rigid body dynamics and am currently exploring the paper "Analytic determination of wrench closure workspace of spatial cable driven parallel mechanisms". In the paper, the derived dynamic model is:

[image]

$\mathrm{Q}$ is a 3x3 matrix which maps the euler angle rates $\dot{\Theta}=[\dot{\psi},\dot{\theta},\dot{\phi}]^T$ into the mobile platform angular velocity: $\omega = \mathrm{Q}\dot{\Theta}$. The term -$\mathrm{J^T}\mathrm{u}$ represents the external wrench exerted on the moving platform due to cable forces. Here, -$\mathrm{J^T}$ denotes the transpose of the Jacobian matrix. In this context, it is called the structure matrix, which is a function of the platform's position, orientation and cable arrangements. And $\mathrm{u}$ is the vector of cable forces.

In Eqns (9) and (11), I am struggling to understand the physical meaning of the $\mathrm{Q^T}$ term? I am aware it is not a rotation matrix, but how $\mathrm{Q^T}$ contributes to calculating the external wrench (moments)? What is the specific role of the "transpose" operation in this context?

Comment: To eliminate from the equations of motion the constraints torques you multiply the EOMs from the left with $~\mathbf Q^T$

Comment: Look here about the theory https://www.amazon.de/Applied-Dynamics-Werner-Schiehlen/dp/3319073346

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the description above $Q$ is the motion Jacobian. This comes from $$\boldsymbol{\omega} = Q \dot{q} \tag{1}$$

The term $(Q^\intercal {\rm I} Q)$ is a projection of the inertial matrix through the joint axis.

Here is the logic behind this statement.

Generalized torques $H$ are defined by

$$H=Q^{\intercal}\boldsymbol{\tau} \tag{2}$$

where $\boldsymbol{\tau}$ is the torque vector. This is result of the power relationship $P=\boldsymbol{\omega}\cdot\boldsymbol{\tau}=\dot{q}^{\intercal}Q^{\intercal}\boldsymbol{\tau}=\dot{q}^{\intercal}H$

So now we are trying to show that

$$H=\left(\text{joint inertia}\right)\ddot{q} + \ldots $$

Consider the angular momentum of the body

$$\boldsymbol{L}={\rm I}\boldsymbol{\omega}={\rm I}Q\dot{q} \tag{3}$$

and the Euler's equation of motion

$$\boldsymbol{\tau}=\dot{\boldsymbol{L}}={\rm I}Q\ddot{q}+\ldots \tag{4}$$

Finally, calculate the generalized torques from the torque vector to find out what the joint inertia term is by using (4) in (2)

$$H=\left(Q^{\intercal}{\rm I}Q\right)\ddot{q}+\ldots$$

**The term $Q^{\intercal}{\rm I}Q$ is interpreted as converting from joint space to cartesian space, applying the inertia matrix, and converting back to joint space.**